# Substract Evals in repeater

Tags: repeater

How can i substract 2 datetime in repeater?
I want to substract 2 requestDates and write to waitingTime.

```
       <td>
        <%#Eval("requestDates")%>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%#Eval("waitingTime")%>
        </td>

         I wanna get like 1 week 4 days 18 hours 47 minutes:>

        ID         Request_Dates                     Waiting_Time
        1      18.01.2012 09:54:38          6 days 20 hours 37 mins 13 sec
        2      11.01.2012 13:17:25                 19 hours 18 mins 47 sec
       ...            ....                                 ....
```

as you see waiting time = (id 1 request_dates) - (id 2 request_dates)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ONE SOLUTION**

You can create a method and call it in your html code, in this way:

```
 <td>
        <%# substraction(Eval("requestDates"),Eval("waitingTime"))%>
        </td>
```

in the cs:

```
public function substraction(....){}
```

Only take into account that you have to cast the variables in the html and cs.

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**
I would replace the Eval with Literals, add an ItemDataBound event and in the method I would find the controls and assign the values, here I can get the values from the "e.Item" object and substract it easily.
For example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound">
.....
</asp:Repeater>

 void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
      {

         MyObject theobject=(MyObject) e.Item.DataItem;
         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {

            // Retrieve the Label control in the current DataListItem.
            Label ltRequest = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ltRequest");
          ltRequest.text=theobject.requestDates;
        ....
        /**HERE I CAN DO WHATEVER***/
     }
}
```

Comment: well i just wondered, is there any way to do it without using item_bound. Thank you for your response.

Comment: tried first approach and i'm getting System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType1...  ' public string Substraction(object obj)
        {
            return "test " + obj;
        }           <%# Substraction(Eval("requestDates"))%> '

Comment: Try doing a cast to the parameters, for example, a Convert.ToString(), and in the substraction method, the parameters as a string. It works for me.